# ComboBox Selected Item gets null

Tags: c#, wpf

I have set GenericCollection of an entity with it's ID property set to 0 initially and set a combobox Itemsource to this generic collection. Whose Selected Value is bound Twoway to another entity's property.

When I save my data, Generic Collection (custom collection) get an ID assigned from database. Which is also reflected in combo box Itemsource but its selected value gets null.

**XAML:**

```
  <my1:ComboBox Name="cmbLHS" 
                Width="Auto" 
                Height="Auto" 
                Grid.Row="0" 
                Grid.Column="0"    
                IsEditable="False"
                SelectionChanged="cmbLHS_SelectionChanged"
                DisplayMemberPath="VARNAME" 
                SelectedValuePath="Code"
                ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=DataContext.BRPARMINPT}" 
                SelectedValue="{Binding LHSITEMSRCECDE,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Even after data is saved PropertyChanged gets called but when I check Combobox SelectedItem in SelectionChanged Event handler it is null.

Comment: Why do you use a SelectionChanged event handler *and* a binding to SelectedValue?

Comment: I can not relate your `SelectedValuePath="Code"` to your text, where you talk about `ID`

Comment: Cant you use `SelectedItem` insted of `SelectedValue`

Comment: @nvoigt.....I am populating another combobox based on selected value of this one that is why I am using SelectionChanged Event handler.

Comment: @grek40.....My entity has properties like Id,code and varname. Of which Code and varname are entered by user, which are displayed in bounded combobox. But id remains 0 until user saves data in db in which Id is an autoincremented field. That value of Id is then reflected in itemsource of comboBox. This changes selected value of combobox to null.

Comment: @Slasko...tried using 'SelectedItem'  but was not helpfull.

Comment: You need to post your ViewModel (DataContext) out. It looks like a binding error only. By the way, no matter SelectedValue or SelectedItem should work. I would say the majority of people using SelectedItem instead.

Comment: @talalshoukat Either `Code` was entered by the user before the current form opened - then it is irrelevant, or `Code` is modified in the same view context where the combobox is displayed, this could be a problem.